# Absolutely positioned element within relative parent. Need parent to grow to the width of the element inside

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I want to float other divs in.  Within the floating divs, I need the content to be positioned at the bottom because some of them have higher content than others and I don't want them to align on top.  I have tried something like this:

```
.right {
  float:right;
}
.left {
  float:left;
}
.actionCell {
  margin:2px 5px 2px 5px;
  border:1px solid Black;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div id="HeaderText" class="left actionCell"><span style="position:absolute;bottom:0px">Header&nbsp;Text</span></div>
    <div id="SelectedItems" class="left actionCell">10 Selected Items</div>
</div>
```

The one with the span on the inside works, however I need its parent container to grow to its width. Any ideas how to solve this problem without using tables?

Comment: what's the css for id HeaderText and id SelectedItems?

Comment: It should be listed above the html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately absolutely positioned elements no longer interact with their parent, so to get the effect you want, you'd need a hack.  Fortunately, web development abounds with hacks:

**CSS only, using a prop element**

Create a `visibility: hidden` element inside your `<div id="HeaderText">` that has the same content as your absolutely positioned `<span>`.  This will force the width of `<div id="HeaderText">` to contain your absolute `<span>`.

On the downside, this duplicates content that anyone without CSS (and search engines) will see.

**jQuery to get absolute child's width**

Set the width `<div id="HeaderText">` to that of its absolute `<span>` child.  This gets around the duplicate content, but your users need Javascript.

You can see them both [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/nbBrj/1/).

Comment: Ok, is there any way to get IE to position the contents to the bottom of the div without using absolute positioning?  I have tried things like vertical-align:bottom, but nothing appears to work.

Comment: You could do something like: `<div id="HeaderText" class="left actionCell" style="line-height: 280px">`